# Type guard failed when using union typed value for props

Tags: typescript

I have the below code snippet:

```js
interface PluginHook {
    onStoreCreated?: (p1: number) => void;
    onModel?: (p2: string) => void;
}

interface MyPlugin extends PluginHook {
    config?: Record<string, unknown>;
}

interface Bag {
    forEachPlugin: <Hook extends keyof PluginHook>(
        method: Hook,
        fn: (content: NonNullable<PluginHook[Hook]>) => void
    ) => void
}

type Method = keyof PluginHook;

function fn(p: NonNullable<PluginHook[Method]>) { }

const plugins: MyPlugin[] = [];

const bag: Bag = {
    forEachPlugin(method, fn): void {
        for (const plugin of plugins) {
            // const mmthod: keyof PluginHook = 'onStoreCreated';
            const hook = plugin[method]
            if (hook) {
                fn(hook)
            }
        }
    },
}
```

In `forEachPlugin`, the type guard for `hook` seems to fail to work. The hook was still undefined so i cant pass it to a NonNullable value.

I code like this previously and opened an issue on [TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40429).

```js
// ...
const bag: Bag = {
    forEachPlugin(method, fn): void {
        for (const plugin of plugins) {
            if (plugin[method]) {
                fn(plugin[method])
            }
        }
    },
}
```

But they said not a bug if i change to this:

```js
const bag: Bag = {
    forEachPlugin(method, fn): void {
        for (const plugin of plugins) {
            const hook = plugin[method]
            if (hook) {
                fn(hook)
            }
        }
    },
}
```

It worked in some cases but also failed in my case. I think it was also a bug. If not, is there any workaround to resolve this? Full code on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `const hook = plugin[method] ?? undefined;` works, but I don't know why

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked like a charm. But I also want to know why.